# How do I unit test an .net 7.0 isolated service bus queue triggered function app using Moq and xUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

With .net 7.0, the payload that comes in for a service bus queue triggered isolated function app comes with the type of **ServiceBusReceivedMessage**. When I go to mock out the Body property on the ServiceBusReceivedMessage using Moq, I realize that the property is get only and not able to set.

```
Mock<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> _serviceBusReceivedMessageMock = new Mock<ServiceBusReceivedMessage>();
var messageBody = _configuration["ServiceBusReceivedMessageTest"];
var bytesMessageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody);
_serviceBusReceivedMessageMock.SetupGet(x => x.Body).Returns(new BinaryData(bytesMessageBody));
```

In order to work around this, I tried to implement reflection on the **ServiceBusReceivedMessage**, but when I tried to initialize it with a constructor and without, it would give errors saying that no constructor exists for it.

```
var messageBody = _configuration["ServiceBusReceivedMessageTest"];
var bodyProperty = typeof(ServiceBusReceivedMessage)
    .GetProperty("Body", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var desiredBody = new BinaryData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
bodyProperty.SetValue(_serviceBusReceivedMessageMock.Object, desiredBody);
_serviceBusReceivedMessageMock.Setup(m => m.Body).Returns(new BinaryData(messageBody));
```

When looking at ways to implement reflection a lot of the time wrappers would be used, but even if those worked, my Azure Function App expects the type of **ServiceBusReceivedMessage** and I wouldn't be able to pass the wrapper into my function app run() method because then it would throw errors since it's expecting the **ServiceBusReceivedMessage** type and not the wrapper type.

So the question still remains is how do I mock out a get only property that isn't able to be reflected and then pass that same model to my method? Even if it means using different testing frameworks or packages to resolve this, I am perfectly okay with that.

Comment: The only different between get and set is set has a body (content).  If set is not working than the Content-Type (http header) is not matching the data in the body.  There is also a length header that has to match the size of the body.  Some libraries automatically calculate the length and other libraries you have to set the length in code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. It seems you are talking about HTTP, while I mean the getting and setting of properties in a C# class. Also, I am not using HTTP and I am instead using Service Bus Queue called from its corresponding test class...

Comment: Microsoft is not very clear (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads).  It is HTTP as described on link.  What I think is happening is Microsoft (Azure) created a seamless server interface that automatically transfers the front end (client - server) data to the backend (server - database).  I think using Raw may solve issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage?view=azure-dotnet#methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your function don't pass a mocked `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`. Instead, create an instance using supplies by the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package the Functions SDK uses for the trigger. To create an instance of `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`, use `ServiceBusModelFactory` specifically designed for test scenarios, invoking [`ServiceBusModelFactory.ServiceBusReceivedMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmodelfactory.servicebusreceivedmessage?view=azure-dotnet) static factory method.

Comment: This worked and now I will be able to override it, thanks for that Sean! I didn't get to be able to implement this until now but thanks for this. I feel like this should be a higher priority as anybody who uses Services Buses and is unit testing them with this specific type instead of using a string will run into this issue. If you'd be so kind, how did you find the solution so quickly? Also, should the priority of testing service buses happen at a higher level like integration tests to test the full process or is unit testing the better approach?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm spending a lot of time with ASB so I have been exposed to these things in my day work. I would not test ASB itself. Rather, like you suggested, focus on testing what's using ASB. And use a real service, not a replacement.